# Jekyll Front Matter custom fields in _posts .md (markdown) not available in liquid tag

Tags: post, markdown, jekyll, liquid

I am aware you can add and use html page custom front matter fields using the {{ page.myField }} directive but this does not work for posts (i.e. when iterating site.posts in a for loop.

My problem, what I have done ...

1. I created a new post in _posts with a .md extension containing new custom front matter fields (it is published and refixed correctly with date) - Seems correct
2. I loop all the posts using  {% for post in site.posts %} - This works
3. When I attempt to use these using a liquid tag {{ post.myNewField }} it is not available but does show in post.content as text not a useable field.

Surely this cannot be correct.  I would assume anything in the markdown in the front matter section should be accessible, as it seems to say so in the Jekyll front matter instruction 
http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/#custom-variables

Please help.

Comment: And your post is starting with a yaml-header, containing the variables, enclosed with three dashes (---)?

Comment: Not really easy to reproduce. Where did 3. happends ?   Did you use `{{ post.myNewField }}` in the post itself, in `layouts/post.html` ?   Maybe you have a github repository url to submit.

Comment: yes posts start with '---' yaml-header.  3 happens in another index.html file, the for loop is inside this html file.  github repo is private.

Comment: I am thinking this link may help me http://wolfslittlestore.be/2013/10/rendering-markdown-in-jekyll/

Answer (score 0):

cause of my issue was UTF-8-DOM encoding when it should have just been UTF-8 encoding for .md files